# Variáveis em um JSON

Tags: php, json, api, asp.net-web-api

Há alguma forma de variar o valor de um JSON? Vamos a um exemplo:

Tenho o seguinte JSON

```
{
    "ISteamClient": 0,
    "ISteamFriends": 0,
    "ISteamUser": 0,
    "IEconItems_440": 0,
    "IEconItems_730": 0,
    "ISteamGameCoordinator_440": 0,
    "ISteamGameCoordinator_570": 0
}
```

Depois de usar

```
$clientesteam = $json_str["ISteamCliente"];
echo "O Cliente Steam esta $clientesteam";
```

O resultado serial: O cliente Steam esta 0

Há alguma forma de transformar esse "0" em "Online"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há várias formas, não sei se entendi. Para você conseguir respostas focados no que você quer você tem que caprichar na pergunta. Perguntas ruins geram respostas fora do alvo. Mas vou tentar já dizendo que se entendi o objetivo, seu problema não tem nada com o JSON ou APIs, é algoritmo bem básico:

```
$clientesteam = $json_str["ISteamCliente"];
echo "O Cliente Steam esta " . ($clientesteam == 0 ? "Online" : "Offline");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/ZUWszA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/JsonPHP). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/Json.php).

[Documentação do operador ternário](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: Em Partes Funcionou , somente resultou em "Online", pode ver o resultado em http://leonardo.noip.me , agora para exibir "Offline" caso o valor seje "1" o codigo seria echo "O Cliente Steam esta " . $clientesteam == 0 ? "Online" : 1 ?"Offline";

Comment: Eu atualizei no ideone mostrando que com 1 funciona normal. Não tem que mexer nada na sintaxe para funcionar. Na verdade eu acho esta manipulação uma forma ingênua, eu tenho minhas dúvidas se vai funcionar em todos os casos mas  eu só posso responder em cima do que você postou.

Comment: Meu Código esta assim http://ideone.com/qA4LeS , só quero que quando o valor for "0" seja exibido Online e quando o valor for "1" seja exibido Offline , pois o JSON vem de um site externo que diz se o Cliente Steam Steam ON ou OFF

Comment: E qual é o problema que você está vendo nele?

Comment: a frase "O Cliente Steam esta" não aparece , somente aparece "Online" ,mas acho que resolvi fazendo uma gambiarra com html.<p> O Cliente Steam está <?php echo "" . $clientesteam == 0 ? "Online" : "Offline"; ?> </p>

Comment: Fazer gambiarras, fazer funcionar por coincidência nunca é uma boa ideia. Eu editei, o que eu postei aqui na resposta está diferente do que eu mostrei executando, eu tinha esquecido os parenteses. Mas a demonstração do ideone já estava certo.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, Obrigado.... eu faço cada pergunta idiota aqui no Stackoverflow , Estou tentando aprender PHP sozinho.

Comment: Exatamente isto é o que você precisa fazer. Vá aprender, não tente fazer sem saber. Fatalmente você vai cometer muitos erros "invisíveis" e não perceberá até que cause um problema maior.

Comment: @LeonardoRoberto Não acho sua pergunta idiota. Pode até ser básica, mas todo mundo que programa em PHP ou qualquer linguagem teve perguntas básicas. Sinta-se livre para perguntar sempre que tiver qualquer dúvida. Com o tempo você vai aprendendo a transmitir melhor suas dúvidas.